# org-babel shell session not starting

Tags: org-babel

I'm trying to write some shell code blocks in a session, but it seems no session has been started, and all the code blocks are run independently. Here is a simple example:

```
* org-babel
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args:shell :session babel
:END:

#+begin_src sh
pwd
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: /Users/olivier/git/mybrain


#+begin_src sh
cd ..
pwd
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: /Users/olivier/git

#+begin_src sh
pwd
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: /Users/olivier/git/mybrain
```

As can be see from above, I changed the working directory to the parent folder in the second block, but it went back to the original folder in the next block.

But I do know the session is not working, because there is a background buffer `babel` opened in the background, but it's an empty buffer with `:no process` written at the bottom.

Can someone tell me what's going on and how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. the language name here is `sh`, not `shell`
2. the colon is missing after the language name

The following works:

```
* org-babel
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args:sh: :session babel
:END:

#+begin_src sh
pwd
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: /Users/olivier/git/mybrain

#+begin_src sh
cd ..
pwd
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: /Users/olivier/git

#+begin_src sh
pwd
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: /Users/olivier/git
```

Comment: Agree with 1. and 2. but not with 3.  - the name of the session can (within reason) be anything one wishes. Try with `foo-bar-baz*` e.g.

Comment: @NickD Indeed, thanks!

Comment: Thanks @JeanPierre and @NickD! I was under the impression that `sh` is just an alias for `shell`, but apparently it's not so.

Comment: Indeed it is, as is every other name in `org-babel-shell-names`, but you have to be consistent:if you decide to use, say, `bash` for the name of the language of the source blocks, you got to use the sane name in the `:header-args:bash` spec e.g. Babel just matches the string to figure out whether the header arg applies to a given source block.

Comment: Also, you should probably use `C-c C-x p` to add the property `:header-args:shell` - that would take care of the missing colon in @JeanPierre's point 2. Note that *that* colon is part of the property syntax, not part of the header arg spec, which is just `:header-args:shell`.

Comment: C-c C-x p asks for the propetry name (I type `header-args`) then the property value (I type `bash`, but the output is then `:header-args: bash`.  What am I missing?